# Adding Event Listener on button - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-listener

I'm trying to add an event listener on button added dynamically to a google maps infowindow.

```
  var contentString = '<br></br>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnDirection">Get direction</button> </div>' +
     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnDiscount">Related discount</button> </div>';

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         position: place.geometry.location,
         icon: './Google_Maps_Markers/darkgreen_MarkerK.png'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);

        var btn = $(contentString).filter('#btnDirection'); 
        if(btn != null){
             for(var i=0; i<btn.length; i++){
                  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function()           
                       { console.log("hello") });
             };
         };   
 });
```

Buttons are displayed on each infowindow, but when I click on nothing heppens.

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: This documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener) indicates that you should be using `addDomListener`, not `addListener`

Comment: You're creating a new object `$(contentString)`. Try `$(infoWindow.getContent()).find("#btnDirection").addEventListener(....)` or even better `$("body").on("click", "#btnDirection", function(){....})`

Comment: I don't get problem with event.addListener. What is not working is when I click on the button displayed on infowindow.

Comment: I tried it. I'm getting now addEventListener is not a function.

Comment: The second one works but it's performing action with all buttons when I click on one of them since that I am adding buttons with the same id to infowindows.  Do you know how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the infowindow is added to the DOM asynchronously, so it can't be found until the [`InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) "domready" event fires.

From [that documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow)):

> **domready** | Arguments:  None
>   This event is fired when the  containing the InfoWindow's content is attached to the DOM. **You may wish to monitor this event if you are building out your info window content dynamically.**

To attach event listeners to those buttons, run the JQuery code to look for them in a 'domready' event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.open(map, this);
  // wait for the infowindow's domready event
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    // find the elements with the "btn" class and add the click listener to the one with id="btnDirection"
    var btn = $(".btn").filter('#btnDirection');
    if (btn != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log("hello")
        });
      };
    };
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ya1nse6t/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var contentString = '<div id="other"></div><br></br>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnDirection">Get direction</button> </div>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnDiscount">Related discount</button> </div>';

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: map.getCenter(), // place.geometry.location,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
    // wait for the infowindow's domready event
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
      // find the elements with the "btn" class and add the click listener to the one with id="btnDirection"
      var btn = $(".btn").filter('#btnDirection');
      if (btn != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
          btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById("other").innerHTML = "Get Direction was CLICKED";
            console.log("hello")
          });
        };
      };
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);

        $('#btnDirection').bind('click', function() {          
            console.log("hello direction") 
        }); 

        $('#btnDiscount').bind('click', function() {          
            console.log("hello discount") 
        }); 
 });
```

Full code:

```js
 var contentString = '<br></br>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnDirection">Get direction</button> </div>' +
     '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnDiscount">Related discount</button> </div>';

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         icon: './Google_Maps_Markers/darkgreen_MarkerK.png'
  });

  var map;
  $(document).ready(function(){
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     position: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
    });
    
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
   infoWindow.open(map, this);

   $('#btnDirection').bind('click', function() {          
    alert("hello direction") 
   }); 

   $('#btnDiscount').bind('click', function() {          
    alert("hello discount") 
   }); 
  });
     }
  
  initMap();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map" style="height:100vh;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution does work for the piece of code you have posted in your original question. If you have other elements in your page with id btnDirection then it wouldn't work but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

if u will same id then event will file on all the button with same id,u should use different Id for each button.

Comment: Please explain your question  in detail ?

Comment: More importantly, if this *is* indeed a question, please do not ask it in an answer. Please see [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask a new question instead.

Answer (score -1):

When dynamically adding content to the DOM (as the `infoWindow`-Content), you have to register the eventListener on a parent element that's existing prior to the event-binding (e.g. the `body` or the `map`-Container).

You can achieve this by doing the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);

    $('body').on('click', '#btnDirection', function() {
        console.log('Hello');
    });
});
```

> The second one works but it's performing action with all buttons when I click on one of them since that I am adding buttons with the same id to infowindows. Do you know how can I fix this ?

IDs should be unique! Use classes for elements with the same use/meaning. Sorry for answering this question here, I can't add a comment on the main question (not enough reputation yet).

Comment: Can you give me more expanations ? How can I make the id unique for each button ? and why does it work even with the same id ?